# `aws opensearch` command is missing in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to update AWS Opensearch using following command but "opensearch" command is missing!

```
aws opensearch start-service-software-update --domain-name <my-domain-name> --schedule-at "NOW"
```

AWS CLI Version: aws-cli/2.2.3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like opensearch is not supported in aws-cli/2.2.3 version.

Updating AWS CLI would resolve issue.

AWS CLI Update steps:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
```

*`aws-cli/2.11.4` version has opensearch command.*